# Implement GetEnumerator for ITuple type objects to be used in foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, tuples, ienumerable

So I had to refactor some code and now I'm trying to iterate to some ITuple objects and add them to a list as you could see below.

```
       //for the case when we have an object of type IList this works
            if (obj is IList) {
            var list = new List<GuiValue>();
            foreach (var o in (IList)obj) {
                list.Add(MethodResultToGuiValue(o));
            }
            return new GuiValue.GV_list(list);
        }
        // this is what I'm interested to solve
        if (obj is ITuple) {
            var list = new List<GuiValue>();
            foreach (var o in (ITuple)obj) {
                list.Add(MethodResultToGuiValue(o));
            }
            return new GuiValue.GV_tuple(list);
        }
```

So the problem that I have it's clear:

[image]

> Type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ITuple' cannot be used in 'foreach' statement because ie neither implements 'IEnumerable' of 'IEnumerable',nor has suitable 'GetEnumerator' method which return type has 'Current' property and 'Move' method.

I did exactly what it was suggested, created a new class TupleExtensions.cs,
and made the extension method in order to do that.

```
internal static class TupleExtensions {

    internal static IEnumerable GetEnumerator(this ITuple tuple) {
        return tuple.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(property => property.GetValue(tuple));
    }
}
```

But I'm still getting the above-mentioned error.

Comment: "exactly what it was suggested" - no, you implemented an extension method. No part of the message suggests that extension methods can be used here.

Comment: Yes, @Damien_The_Unbeliever I thought that that would be one solution to it. How else can I use the 'GetEnumerator' method?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "iterate" through the `ItemX` properties, you can't just do

```cs
foreach (var o in (ITuple)obj)
```

since `ITuple` does not implement `IEnumerable`. However, you can do the following

```cs
if (obj is ITuple tuple) // Minor improvement to keep the result of the cast
{
   // .....
   foreach (var o in tuple.GetEnumerator()) // Explicitly get the IEnumerable
   {
     // ......
   }
   // rest of your code
}
```